# VueJS - Vee-Validate: Custom rule to call method/function to evaluate a result?

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

Sorry, I'm still very new to VueJS and it's framework.

I'm trying to use vee-validate and a custom rule to check the value of an input field against an Axios GET response to an API backend.  Essentially, if you input an invalid ID, it will throw up an error until you get it right (ie: assigning a ticket to a valid employee, you must enter a valid employee ID).

My template code looks like this right now:

```
     <b-col cols="4">
        <b-input-group>
          <b-input-group-text style="width:150px;" slot="prepend">Key Owner</b-input-group-text>
          <input
            class="form-control"
            v-model="selected_owner_id"
            type="text"
            id="ownerId"
            name="ownerId"
            data-vv-delay="800"
            @change="validateCorpId"
            v-validate="'ownerId|required'"
            v-bind:class="{'form-control': true, 'error': errors.has('ownerId') }"
          >
        </b-input-group>
        <span v-show="errors.has('ownerId')" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('ownerId') }}</span>
      </b-col>
```

(I am messing around with how to do this, hence the @change to the function that actually does the Axios API call)

Here is the Validate extend rule I have made in the same *.vue file as above:

```
<script>
import { Validator } from "vee-validate";
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'

Validator.extend('ownerId', {
  // Custom validation message
  getMessage: (field) => `The ${field} is not a valid ID.`,
  // Custom validation rule
  validate: (value) => new Promise(resolve => {        
    resolve({
        valid: value && (this.validateCorpId(value))
      });
  })
});

...etc...
```

The validateCorpId(value) function is later on in the methods: {} block

I have been trying to go through the Vee-Validate docs on how to properly create a custom validation rule but as a newbie, a lot of things still seem missing like, where should that Validate.extend actually sit?  Where I put it up top in the 'script' area or inside either the 'create' or 'mount' functions?

I did try that and it gets called right away which isnt what I want -- i only want it to happen when you the user enter or change the data in the field that it calls the function which returns a true|false value.

I also added a field called is_selected_owner_id_valid into the 'data' return block and had my Axios call set that true|false depending on the result but, as it's a boolean, the Validate rule read it immediately and it evaluated incorrectly.

I'm happy to keep working it our for myself, but does anyone have a fully working Validate custom rule I could see and reverse-engineer ?  Really hard to find an example of what I am trying to do, involving an API call as part of the rule.

Comment: Hi ehthreeone did you see this example? you should modify the isUnique method for your api call and also adapt the responses:
https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/async-backend-validation.html

Comment: I think that is exactly what I want.  I did manage to get mine working by copying this person's example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106256/vee-validate-vuejs-evaluating-a-condition-asynchronously?rq=1

But I wasn't sure how correct it was to put the actual APi call in the custom rule itself.  I like that example you provided and will retro fit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get my issue resolved by initially copying this similar posted answer here:

[Vee-validate (VueJS) - evaluating a condition asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106256/vee-validate-vuejs-evaluating-a-condition-asynchronously?rq=1)

While it works, I'm not convinced about having the actual APi call in the custom rule.  However, thanks to the suggestion by Walter Cejas, I'm going to retro fit my solution into that example provided : https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/async-backend-validation.html

(I thought I had gone through all the vee-validate examples...  i was wrong!)